# Array to String conversion but var_dump only show Strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, pdo

Alright so I'm getting an 
Array to string conversion error
on this line of code

```
$addStmt = $db->prepare($addSql);
```

here the full line of code

```
$btnVal = $_REQUEST['btnInput'];

        if($btnVal[0] == 'add') {
            $enteredInput = $_POST["userInput"];
            $addSql = "INSERT INTO tasks (userID,lists,done) VALUES(:id, :list, :done)";
            $addStmt = $db->prepare($addSql);

            $addStmt->execute([":id" => $_SESSION['userID'], ":list" =>$list, ":done"=>0]);
            print_r($addStmt);
        }
```

and here is my form code

```
 echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="userInput" name="userInput">';
 echo '<button type="submit" class="btn" value="add" name="btnInput[]">Add</button>';
```

I also have buttons for delete, update following the same code but with different values.
Now my thinking is oh just find out what one is outputting an array and turn it into a string, but var_dump show all of them are already strings values

Comment: which value do you dump?

Comment: I found my trouble within a minute of pressing the submit button on this I really need to learn to not try and code for a whole day non stop it messes with your eyes

Comment: why button submit have name representing array? `name="btnInput[]"`

Comment: Assume the answer is `$btnVal[0][0] ==`? or iterate over that?

Comment: because I was trying all kinds of things to get the code to work, but yeah I don't really need that and it been removed now

Comment: Is your problem resolved else share full code so that we can figure out where exactly the problem is

Comment: The code above would not create the error you gave on the line you mentioned. However since you mentioned you got it to work, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: my issue was in fact fixed I would close this if I knew how